# Prevent Firefox internet connectivity or script execution while Mac is Locked

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, connection

I have already done a ton of googling about this, and all I'm getting is irrelevant results.

I'm trying to prevent any internet connections OR script executions by my browsers (or at least Firefox), while my Mac is locked.

Thanks

Comment: Specifically browser-based, or do you effectively want the network to be disabled while the machine is under lock status?

Comment: browser-based or app-based would do it... I can't find anything on the google on this topic.